# How to fix access DOM in a loop using prompt

Tags: javascript

In a prompt message I request a number, I want to update the DOM element (input) but only work when do -  while ends, I want to update  the DOM after every prompt message.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Odds and Evens Game</title>


</head>

<body>
    <form>
        Number: <input type="text" id="number">
        <input type="button" onclick="showIt()" value="ShowIt"> 
    </form>


<script>
       function showIt(){
 var inputval ;

        do {
        inputval = prompt('Enter a number between 1 and 5 , 999 to exit');
        number = parseInt(inputval);

        document.getElementById('number').value= number;

        }while(number !== 999); 
}
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

sample that is running:
https://jsfiddle.net/neossoftware/73ag8whd/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prompt` window `prevents the user from accessing the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed`. Your while loop is calling prompt again and again blocking the access to user interface.

Use await, to paint the window before calling second prompt.

```js
let num = 0;
let ele = document.querySelector('#num');

(async () => {
    do {
        await getInput()
        ele.value = num;
        await sleep(0);
    } while(num !== 999);
})();

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    })
}

function getInput() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        num = Number(prompt("Enter num"));
        resolve(num);
    });
}
```

```html
Number: <input type="text" id="num">
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question completely as your code does work without error except the last `999` to exit bit (on Firefox, Linux) - as that code then updates your input to `999`. Why do you have this `999 to exit` anyway?

Some minor changes and options below:

```js
function showIt(){
  var inputval, num;
  do {
    inputval = prompt('Enter a number between 1 and 5 (inclusive), 999 to exit');
    num = parseInt(inputval);
    if ((num != NaN) && (num >= 1) && (num <= 5) && (num != 999)) {
      document.getElementById('number').value = num;
    }
  } while (num !== 999);
}

function updateAndExit(e) {
  var inputval = prompt('Enter a number between 1 and 5 (inclusive)');
  var num = parseInt(inputval);
  if ((num != NaN) && (num >= 1) && (num <= 5)) {
    this.textContent = num;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var d = document.getElementById("click-to-udpate");
  if (d) {
    d.addEventListener("click",updateAndExit,false);
  }
}
```

```css
.fakeInput {
  border:1px solid #886;
  padding:6px;
  background:#ddd;
}
.fakeInput:hover {
  border:1px solid #688;
  background:#fff;
  cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
Number: <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="number">
        <input type="button" onclick="showIt()" value="ShowIt"> 
        
<p>
Different option below:
</p>
<div id="click-to-udpate" class="fakeInput">Click to update</div>
```

Comment: The OP want every user input(taken from prompt window) value to be displayed in `input` element. But, the `input` element value is updated once i:e after exit of `do..while` loop.

Comment: @randomSoul : Not on Firefox on Linux. The input _is_ update every time for me and then replaced when changed again. This may be a limitation (feature) of the browser used. If the user wanted the values concatenated, that is something different but only minor to change.